# Select records from 2 tables based on 3rd mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables with the below Structure.
Company - table 1

```
Id  
Name  
Phone
```

Contact - table 2

```
Id  
FirstName  
LastName  
CellPhone  
Phone  
Phone2  
Email1
```

Company_Contact - table 3

```
CompanyId  
ContactId
```

One company can have multiple contacts. Now i want to Select 
Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Company.Name, Contact.CellPhone, Contact.Phone, Contact.Phone2, Company.Phone, Contact.Email1 for all companies

Comment: Just a small tip: if one contact cannot be part of multiple companies, you should store the CompanyID in the Contact table, instead of using an intersection table (Company_Contact in your case). That way your contacts are directly linked to their company.

Comment: one contact can connect with multiple companies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to know the fields that you want to select and relate them

```
SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Company.Name, Contact.CellPhone,
Contact.Phone, Contact.Phone2, Company.Phone, Contact.Email1 
FROM contact, company, company_contact 
WHERE company.id = Company_Contact.companyId and contact.id = company_contact.contactId
```

I think that's what u want
maybe there are errors, but this is the logic of the question

Answer (score 2):

You need simple join

```
select Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Company.Name, Contact.CellPhone, Contact.Phone, Contact.Phone2, Company.Phone, Contact.Email1 
from Company 
inner join Company_Contact on Company.id = Company_Contact.CompanyId  
inner join Contact on Contact.id = Company_Contact.ContactId
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Company.Name, Contact.CellPhone, Contact.Phone, Contact.Phone2, Company.Phone, Contact.Email1  
FROM Company, Contact, Company_Contact 
WHERE Company_Contact.CompanyId = Company.Id AND Company_Contact.ContactId = Contact.Id
```